Proving an inequality given a constraint
Given $a,b,c >0 $ and $ab+bc+ca=3$ prove the following inequality :
$\large 3\left( \frac1{a} + \frac1{b} +\frac1{c} \right) \geqslant 6 + \frac{ab}{c} +\frac{bc}{a} + \frac{ca}{b}$
My work : LHS$= 3 \cdot \frac{ab+bc+ca}{abc} = \frac{9}{abc}\\ \geqslant 6 +\frac{ab}{c} +\frac{bc}{a} + \frac{ca}{b}$
By AM-GM : $ab+bc+ca=3 \geqslant 3 \sqrt[3]{(abc)^2 } \implies abc\leqslant1$
$\frac{9}{abc} \geqslant 9 \geqslant6+ \frac{ab}{c} +\frac{bc}{a} + \frac{ca}{b}$
$\frac{ab}{c} +\frac{bc}{a} + \frac{ca}{b} \leqslant 3$
$(ab)^2 +(bc)^2 +(ca)^2 \leqslant 3 $
Am I on the right track , if yes, how to continue further ?

We have
$$3\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)-\left(6+\frac{ab}c+\frac{bc}a+\frac{ca}b\right)$$
$$=3\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)-\left(6+\frac{ab}c+\frac{bc}a+\frac{ca}b\right)+\frac{3(ab+bc+ca-3)+(ab+bc+ca-3)^2}{abc}$$
$$=2a+2b+2c-6$$
Note $9\le\frac{(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2}2~~~~+3(ab+bc+ca)=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca=(a+b+c)^2$.
Therefore, $3\le a+b+c$ so $2a+2b+2c-6\ge0$ so $$3\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)\ge6+\frac{ab}c+\frac{bc}a+\frac{ca}b$$
